# Where can _Static_assert declarations be used?

Tags: language-lawyer, c11, static-assert

This is a valid C11 translation unit that will compile without warnings with GCC 5.1 and Clang 3.7:

```
_Static_assert(1, "Test.");

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

According to [the draft standard N1570](//www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), `_Static_assert` can be produced from the `declaration` (see section 6.7) and `struct-declaration` (see section 6.7.2.1) nonterminals. **I want to stress that last one:** it seems that where you can make any declaration, including the declaration of union or struct tags, you can also make a static assertion.

But can you really use them everywhere?

## In the optional declaration list?

Note that the `function-definition` nonterminal (see section 6.9.1) optionally contains a `declaration-list`. I would think that a static declaration can be included here:

```
int main(void)
    _Static_assert(1, "Test.");
{
    return 0;
}
```

However, GCC 5.1 complains:

> ```
> main.c:2:5: error: expected declaration specifiers before '_Static_assert'
> ```

Clang 3.7 has similar complaints about the program.

## In the first argument of a `for` statement?

Let's take this program:

```
int main(void) {
    for (_Static_assert(1, "Test."); 0; );

    return 0;
}
```

Even though the first argument of `for` can either be an expression or a declaration since C99, and even though GCC accepts this program, Clang says:

> ```
> main.c:2:10: error: expected identifier or '('
> ```

---

Are these defects in the implementations, or am I missing some constraint in the draft specification that disallows the use of `_Static_assert` in these cases?